# I saw this ball of light moving across the sky

Tags: star

As I stated in the title, I saw this ball of light moving across the sky. It wasn't moving fast, but it wasn't moving slow.

So, I was sitting my dad's car when I looked through the windshield and at the sky to see a ball of (white) light moving across the sky. It wasn't small like the other stars, it was actually really big compared to them. It was kind of quickly moving across the sky before it faded. I thought it was a pane but the light didn't re-appear.  I then thought it was a shooting star, but after some research, I realised I was once again wrong.

I've seen this before, yet I still can't find out what it is.

Maybe some of you know what it is..?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a reflection from something on the ground, like a distant passing car or bicycle light. The surfaces of the glass windshield (any dielectric) weakly reflect light, so intense sources like lights can sometimes appear to be coming from the sky.

Comment: Why did you rule out a meteor? Occasionally there is a very bright one.

Comment: What was the date? Time? Your location? Time zone (if not apparent from your location.) What does fast mean to you? What does slow mean? Did it take 5 minutes to cross the sky/half the sky/a quarter of the sky? Did it take 5 seconds to cross the sky/half the sky/a quarter of the sky. Without some details, we can only make a guess about what you saw. (It could have been a bright meteor or a satellite or a non-astronomical object.)

Comment: If it was about sunrise or sunset it might be ISS or a plane reflection.

Comment: It could be also a sattelite, or sky lantern (called also Chinese lantern) for instance.

Comment: Was it really bright and did any astronauts wave to you? Then you can be pretty sure that it is ISS (International Space Station). ISS suddenly shows, moves slowly and then faster until it is very high, then starts decelerating and it suddenly disappears as it has appeared. Look at the site Heavens-Above, and you can plan to observe ISS on your own because it is very nice that you actually look at the living astronauts. You can also check if it was really ISS. But on this Stack Exchange, we don't ask questions, which ask for an opinion or debate. For these purposes, there are astronomy forums.